# How to make a 2D Terrain with opengl?

Tags: opengl, 2d, libgdx, terrain-rendering, vertex

I want to make a simple 2d terrain with just a few bumps and height changes:

[image: terrain with le car]

I thought about just using random numbers to describe the height of a certain vertex, but I don't see how I can make one mesh from this. I'm looking for a way to find the vertex and indices buffers for the terrain.
How do I do this?

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13015/how-to-create-2d-game-terrain

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a triangle strip. You could have your random heights at intervals equal to t. So the triangle strip would then consist of you alternating between the height vertices (with y being random and x equal to t * iteration) and vertices that go along the bottom (with y being constant and x also equal to t * iteration).

[image]

Naturaly, the distance between each vertex pair doesn't have to be constant, this is just an example of the implementation.

Comment: I thought about how to do this and this answer makes it pretty simple. This actually helps me out with making random asteroid objects.